# My javascript async structure does not work properly. It returns undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am new to javascript and I though my async structure was working properly. I tried to follow a bunch of tutorials but can fix this.

The function is returning the right value in one function but returns undefined even with the async: //This returns "Print > undefined"

```js
function initApp() {
    // Listen for auth state changes.
    // [START authstatelistener]
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
                    if (user) {
                        // User is signed in.
                        var displayName = user.displayName;
                        var email = user.email;
                        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
                        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
                        var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
                        var uid = user.uid;
                        var providerData = user.providerData;

                        await chechPaymentStatus(uid)

                        async function chechPaymentStatus(uid) {
                            let status = await getUserPaymentStatus(uid)
                            console.log("Print > " + status) //This returns "Print > undefined"
                            if (status == "paid") {
                                console.log("o status é  " + status)
                                generateApprovedIntercace()
                            } else {
                                console.log(status)
                                console.log("o status é  " + status)
                                generateNotPaidInterface()
                            }
                        }

                        //Get status from datafire (paid or not)
                        async function getUserPaymentStatus(uid) {
                            var db = firebase.firestore()
                            console.log(uid)
                            db.collection("users").where("user_id", "==", uid).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                                console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].id)
                                user_id = querySnapshot.docs[0].id
                                data = querySnapshot.docs[0].data()
                                if (user_id == uid) {
                                    console.log("é igual")
                                    if (data.paymentStatus == "paid") {
                                        console.log("tá pago")
                                        console.log(data.paymentStatus) //This one returns just fine.
                                        return data.paymentStatus;
                                        // generateApprovedIntercace()
                                    } else {
                                        return "not_paid";
                                        // generateNotPaidInterface()
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that your method `getUserPaymentStatus(uid)` does not return anything and that's why you get `undefined`. There is one condition where this could happen and  it's `if (user_id != uid)`. Is it possible that user_id != uid? Also, if you don't mind me asking, why are you using `==` and not `===`? The strict equality (===) reduces chances of bugs.

Comment: I fixed the "==" to "===" thanks but that is not the reason.

The two console logs work just fine:
console.log("é igual") and console.log("tá pago")
So they do get there. I think...

Comment: Could you also change this line `if (user_id != uid)` to `if (user_id !== uid)` in the `getUserPaymentStatus(uid)` method? Also, to confirm that it's the reason you are getting an undefined value, you can `console.log(user_id != uid)` in the `getUserPaymentStatus(uid)` method. If that returns `true`, that's the source of your bug.

Comment: Nope. It returns false. It doesn ot look like the cause of the problem. 
I still think it's related to an async call, but it looks ok to me :(

Comment: You are right that the async calls look ok. I think @piyush's answer solves the mystery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the return statement before the database call.

`return db.collection("users").where("user_id", "==", uid).get().then((querySnapshot)`

Answer (score 0):

The db.collection("users").where("user_id", "==", uid).get() method is also an async call. So by the time the block inside then is called your getUserPaymentStatus method has already returned undefined.

Maybe use the code [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_1) for reference and have an await for get() as well.

You can define querySnapshot like this and then write the code for your then block

`querySnapshot= await db.collection("users").where("user_id", "==", uid).get();`

Comment: The `.then((querySnapshot)` part of the code does the same thing an `await` would do. Adding an `await` would be redundant.